# Error "You can not access the resource from this browser please use Safari or Edge Browser" with Intune

Tags: ios, sharepoint, intune

Microsoft Intune, As two browser is supported for iOS Safari & Edge. The organisation has protected all the resources if we try to access the resources with another browser.

In our iOS app, we are accessing the Sharepoint web page in Webkit and this Webkit is not recognised as a supported browser by Intune.

I discussed this with the Organisation Admin team, they said to use the Safari browser. As Safari browser works outside/separate the application so I can not use SFSafariViewController.

I checked Microsoft Sharepoint official application they are still using the Webkit inside the app, How they are using the WKWebview for accessing the same web pages with the managed device if Webkit is not supported by Intune.

[image]